# How to force users from specific office location to specific ADFS Server

Tags: dns, active-directory, adfs

I have a unique requirement where my client wants to send request from specific office location to local ADFS first and if that ADFS is not available then send it another one which can be in another office location

They have one ADFS farm already deployed which contains two servers (Primary and Secondary). Now they want to add two more servers to different geographic locations. The idea behind this is that users should be redirected to local ADFS first and if it is not available then they should redirect to another ADFS(which will be preferably between one of the first two servers). I want help in knowing how can this be done. I can think following approaches if they are possible- 
1. Is there any setting in ADFS about this.
2. Can this be achieve from DNS routing
3. Can this be done using some kind of NLB. (If NLB is the option, can you suggest the name)

Answer (score 0):

If your ADFS server has an external endpoint, then you can make sure of Azure Traffic Manager to achieve this scenario. You can use nested profile, where the outer profile will do geographical routing and the inner profile will do priority routing.

Regards, 
Msrini

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But we have some tight budget and are looking for something open source.